# write list to file using display-lines-to-file

Tags: racket

I'm having problems getting the display-lines-to-file working, here is what I have tried:

```
(define (list-to-file lst file) (display-lines-to-file lst file
                               #:exists 'replace
                               #:separator newline #"\n"))

(list-to-file myList "myfile.txt")
```

myList is a list of data that was read from another file, after processing that data I need to write the contents of the list (including newline characters) to myfile.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racket keyword arguments have a `#:keyword` followed by a single value. The problem seems to be:

```
#:separator newline #"\n"
```

Instead you want:

```
#:separator #"\n"
```

I'd suggest a few other changes:

- Since the default for `#:separator` is already `#"\n"`, omit that.
- You may want to add `#:mode 'text` so that `\n` is automatically translated to `\r\n` on Windows.
- Racket allows almost anything in an identifier. Taking advantage of that, by convention "->" is used instead of "-to-" or "-2-".

Combining all that:

```
(define (list->file lst file)
  (display-lines-to-file lst
                         file
                         #:exists 'replace
                         #:mode 'text))
```